# Why does performance decrease with the size of the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, memory

I'm working with a relatively large dataset (approx 5m observations, made up of about 5.5k firms).

I needed to run OLS regressions with a 60 month rolling window for each firm. I noticed that the performance was insanely slow when I ran the following code:

```
for idx, sub_df in master_df.groupby("firm_id"):
    # OLS code
```

However, when I first split my dataframe into about 5.5k dfs and then iterated over each of the dfs, the performance improved dramatically.

```
grouped_df = master_df.groupby("firm_id")
df_list = [group for group in grouped_df]

for df in df_list:
    my_df = df[1]
    # OLS code
```

I'm talking 1-2 weeks of time (24/7) to complete in the first version compared to 8-9 hours tops.

Can anyone please explain **why** splitting the master df into N smaller dfs and then iterating over each smaller df performs better than iterating over the same number of groups within the master df?

Thanks ever so much!

Comment: What did the memory do when you run the first code vs the second.. Did you monitor it?  ... Also what happens after the grouping also might be important more or less the missing `# OLS code`

Comment: Hey. So the memory usage appears to remain at approximately 85% per the Task Manager. This applies in both cases. It's just that in the first instance, it takes AGES to complete, whereas the second case things go a lot quicker.

The post grouping code is identical in both cases.

Comment: I think i need more coffee...  Just noticed `for idx, sub_df in master_df.groupby("firm_id"):` runs in a for loop using (object) functions in a loop in a [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) is 9 out the 10 times a bad idea as is it might need to recall the (object) function on every loop cycle if it does not optimize... Which it feels like is also happening here..

Comment: Howcome you have my_df = df[1], is 1 just the column name you want to perform OLS on? I wonder how the performance would be if you created an OLS function then an apply across the groupby, df.groupby("firm_id").apply(OLS_func).

Comment: df[1] just gets the actual df since when I use list comprehension on the groupby object, the list has N tuples inside, which element 0 of the tuple being the group key, and element 1 being the actual df.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your observation. Here's some code that generates data and then times the direct and indirect methods separately. The time taken is very similar in either case.

Is it possible that you accidentally sorted the dataframe by the group key between the runs? Sorting by group key results in a noticeable difference in run time.

Otherwise, I'm beginning to think that there might be some other differences in your code. It would be great if you could post the full code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def generate_data():
  ''' returns a Pandas DF with columns 'firm_id' and 'score' '''
  # configuration
  np.random.seed(22)
  num_groups = 50000 # number of distinct groups in the DF
  mean_group_length = 200 # how many records per group?
  cov_group_length = 0.10 # throw in some variability in the num records per group
  
  # simulate group lengths
  stdv_group_length = mean_group_length * cov_group_length
  group_lengths = np.random.normal(
    loc=mean_group_length,
    scale=stdv_group_length,
    size=(num_groups,)).astype(int)
  group_lengths[group_lengths <= 0] = mean_group_length
  
  # final length of DF
  total_length = sum(group_lengths)
  
  # compute entries for group key column
  firm_id_list = []
  for i, l in enumerate(group_lengths):
    firm_id_list.extend([(i + 1)] * l)
    
  # construct the DF; data column is 'score' populated with Numpy's U[0, 1)
  result_df = pd.DataFrame(data={
      'firm_id': firm_id_list,
      'score': np.random.rand(total_length)
    })
    
  # Optionally, shuffle or sort the DF by group keys
  
  # ALTERNATIVE 1: (badly) unsorted df
  result_df = result_df.sample(frac=1, random_state=13).reset_index(drop=True)
  # ALTERNATIVE 2: sort by group key
  # result_df.sort_values(by='firm_id', inplace=True)
  return result_df

def time_method(df, method):
  ''' time 'method' with 'df' as its argument '''
  t_start = datetime.now()
  method(df)
  t_final = datetime.now()
  delta_t = t_final - t_start
  print(f"Method '{method.__name__}' took {delta_t}.")
  return

def process_direct(df):
  ''' direct for-loop over groupby object '''
  for group, df in df.groupby('firm_id'):
    m = df.score.mean()
    s = df.score.std()
  return

def process_indirect(df):
  ''' indirect method: generate groups first as list and then loop over list '''
  grouped_df = df.groupby('firm_id')
  group_list = [pair for pair in grouped_df]
  for pair in group_list:
    m = pair[1].score.mean()
    s = pair[1].score.std()

df = generate_data()
time_method(df, process_direct)
time_method(df, process_indirect)
```